# Android Studio 3.5 Reformat Code in XML files issues

Tags: android-studio

After executing the shortcut (Ctrl + Alt + L) to reformat the code in some xmls files, some components have their positions changed.

For example, a button that was at the bottom of a layout is thrown to the top after reformatting, unconfiguring the entire layout.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Is there any solution?

This started happening after update Android Studio to version 3.5.

Comment: It's a common issue with the 3.5 upgrade. Check the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.